Vertices/edges dissapear when zooming in in Edit mode

Two pics of what I see when I try to zoom in and I don't understand what happened and why did it start acting up like this.
I opened the file with a cat head, then added a cube, moved it to the side, and deleted it in edit mode to start working with the tool "Polybuild". In the process I remember clicking on "merging vertices" and turning on the magnet to the vertices. Then deleted the whatever I made with Polybuild and then came back to look at the cat head and now it was acting weird as per picture. What happened? How do I make vertices/edges look/act normal again?

It looks like there is more than one cat head in the scene, and depending on zoom Blender shows the one you're editing or the other in front. Probably it is something similar like the problem in the following question, check the answer there: Can't select or edit certain parts of my mesh during retopo.
